# How to submit and forward to a new link

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsf

I'm trying to submit the page and forward to a new JSP.

`h:outputlink` will only send me to a new link without submitting the page.
`h:commandlink` requires me to implement a backing bean function and navigation rule which is quite complex if I have many links sending me to many pages.

I'm thinking there's got to be a way to submit and navigate to a new page in a more simple manner.

Anyone?
Tnx!

Update: Used the next navigation rule in conjuction with Bozho answer. 
Works for Chrome but not for IE and Firefox: (Doesn't Work Meaning the redirection doesn't occur and the browser reloads the same page)

This Component: (Shortened)

```
<rich:panelMenu mode="server">
    <rich:panelMenuItem styleClass="configChooserButton" icon="images/email.png"
        disabledClass="configChooserButtonDisabled">
        <h:commandLink value="Email (#{email.numOfInstances})" action="email" />
    </rich:panelMenuItem>
</rich:panelMenu>
```

With this Navigation Rule:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>email</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/emailConfiguration.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that using POST for page-to-page navigation is not SEO friendly. Searchbots won't index POST forms. JSF 2.0 has solved this by providing `<h:link>` (and `<h:button>`) which understands navigation cases, but does a normal GET instead. If SEO is important on your site, I'd recommend to stick to `<h:outputLink>` (or just `<a>`).

Comment: check the request and response with firebug

Comment: @Bozho Thanks! Figured it out - rich:panelMenu should have been set to mode="non"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - in the `action` attribute of `<h:commandLink>` specify the name of the navigation outcome (as defined in `faces-config.xml`)

Comment: You mean in h:outputLink? And that will cause a submit?

Comment: @Bozho But isn't the value tag used to "The text to display to the user for this command component." in commandlink?
Did you mean the action tag?

Comment: @Ben, yes, sorry, I meant the action, yes.

Comment: It doesn't work in Internet Explorer. (Does in Chrome)
Any Idea?

Comment: @Ben - perhaps a javascript error? How exactly is it not working

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the correct answer of Bozho; the OP did not specify which version of JSF is being used, but in JSF 2.0 there is the concept of `implicit navigation`.

This means navigation without XML navigation rules.

For example, if you wanted to go from some page to a page called "new_page.xhtml", you would use the following:

```
<h:commandButton value="something" action="new_page" />
```

*<sub>(As an extra advice for working with JSF, if at all possible try to forget about JSP and use Facelets. JSP is nothing but a big pain here)</sub>*

Comment: +1. I assumed 1.2 since OPs usually mention explicitly if using 2.0. But good to have a 2.0 answer as well.

Comment: Thanks. I really should move to 2.0 someday soon.
But this time 1.2 was right :-)